# T-SQL: AGGREGATE AND/OR CONDITIONAL SUBQUERY ON WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Thanks in advance for your help on this. Here's the the scenario. I have two tables: Lots (stores lot info for food items) and Trans (stores inventory transactions on lot items).

I am trying to write a query that lists all the transactions that are older than 90 days based 3 conditions on the where clause somehow:

1. CurrentQty (on Lots table) > 0
2. If TransactionType = Shipment AND TransactionDate > 90 days (from current date) OR..
3. IF TransactionType = Receipt AND TransactionDate > 90 days (from current date)

Notes: for each lot, there could be many different transactions of the same type, as shown in the attached picture. There could be many shipments or receipts. I need to be able to select the MAX(TransactionDate) for a particular transaction type and check to see if it's over 90 days then show the record.

There will always be at least one of these two transaction types on the transaction table for every lot, either Shipment or Receipt. If there is no shipment transaction type on a particular lot, then I want to use the Max(TransactionDate) > 90 condition for the "receipt" transaction type.

I need to be able to evaluate all these conditions for each lot and it's particular transactions.

Below is the query I started to write, but then got stuck on how to structure the rest.

```
SELECT 
    LOTS.LOTNUMBER, TRANS.ITEMNUMBER, TRANS.DESCRIPTION, 
    TRANS.TRANSACTIONTYPE, TRANS.TRANSACTIONDATE, TRANS.WAREHOUSE, 
    TRANS.QUANTITY
FROM 
    LOTS 
INNER JOIN 
    TRANS ON LOTS.LOTNUMBER = TRANS.LOTNUMBER
WHERE 
    LOTS.CURRENTQUANTITY > 0
```

[image: TABLES]

Comment: PLEASE FIX YOUR CAPS LOCK. IT APPEARS TO HAVE BEEN STUCK WHEN YOU TYPED THE TITLE OF YOUR QUESTION. Either that, or you're being very rude and SHOUTING AT US, in which case you need to stop that as well. We can all read very well, SHOUTING your question will not get you an answer any faster, and SHOUTING AT US is really annoying and impolite behavior.

Comment: Are you limited to one LotNumber at a time per ItemNumber? Otherwise this gets a little weird.

Comment: Hello Ken White, I am sorry, I just joined this forum today and still trying to figure things out including proper protocol. My apologies.

Comment: Hello DaveX,

Thank you for your reply. A lot will always contain one item number only. For example, there will never be a lot that contains apples and pears.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    LOTS.LOTNUMBER, TRANS.ITEMNUMBER, TRANS.DESCRIPTION, 
    TRANS.TRANSACTIONTYPE, TRANS.TRANSACTIONDATE, TRANS.WAREHOUSE, 
    TRANS.QUANTITY
FROM 
    LOTS 
INNER JOIN 
    (Select LotNumber, Max(TransactionDate) MaxTransDate From TRANS Group By LotNumber) Trans ON LOTS.LOTNUMBER = TRANS.LOTNUMBER
WHERE 
    LOTS.CURRENTQUANTITY > 0 And 
    DATEDIFF(d, TRANS.TRANSACTIONDATE, getdate()) > 90 And
    (TRANS.TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'Reciept' Or 
     TRANS.TRANSACTIONTYPE = 'Shipment')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @lots TABLE (
     LotNumber          NVARCHAR(10)
    ,ItemNum            NVARCHAR(12)
    ,CurrentQty         INT
    )

DECLARE @trans TABLE (
     TransNum           INT
    ,ItemNum            NVARCHAR(12)
    ,Description        NVARCHAR(30)
    ,TransType          NVARCHAR(10)
    ,TransDate          DATE
    ,Warehouse          NVARCHAR(5)
    ,Quantity           INT
    )

INSERT INTO @lots VALUES
    ('ABC','10-MAND-5879',925)

INSERT INTO @trans VALUES
     (398741,'10-MAND-5879','10 Lb Mandarin Bag','Receipt','2016-01-01','IXCST',100)
    ,(973541,'10-MAND-5879','10 Lb Mandarin Bag','Shipment','2016-02-04','WTGS',365)
    ,(972547,'10-MAND-5879','10 Lb Mandarin Bag','Receipt','2016-02-29','GKWK',250)
    ,(632403,'10-MAND-5879','10 Lb Mandarin Bag','Shipment','2016-03-01','GWSJ',150)
    ,(692147,'10-MAND-5879','10 Lb Mandarin Bag','Shipment','2016-03-17','ABTK',25)

;WITH MaxShip
    AS (
        SELECT ItemNum, TransNum,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNum ORDER BY TransDate DESC) AS TransOrder
            FROM @trans
                WHERE TransType = 'Shipment'
            ),

MaxRcpt
    AS (
        SELECT ItemNum, TransNum,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNum ORDER BY TransDate DESC)  AS TransOrder
            FROM @trans
                WHERE transtype = 'Receipt'
            )

SELECT *
    FROM @trans t
        LEFT JOIN @lots l
            ON t.ItemNum = l.ItemNum
        JOIN MaxShip ms
            ON ms.TransNum = t.TransNum
    WHERE TransOrder = 1 AND CurrentQty > 0 AND DATEADD(dd,90,TransDate) < GETDATE()
UNION
SELECT *
    FROM @trans t
        LEFT JOIN @lots l
            ON t.ItemNum = l.ItemNum
        JOIN MaxRcpt mr
            ON mr.TransNum = t.TransNum
    WHERE TransOrder = 1 AND CurrentQty > 0 AND DATEADD(dd,90,TransDate) < GETDATE()
```

Comment: Hello DaveX and Joe C, thank you so much for your replies. I have tried both of your solutions, but for some reason I don't get any records back. I should probably clarify this. If there is a "shipment" transaction type, that would be the only thing I care about for evaluating the > 90 condition. On the screenshot sample, there is a highlightted record in yellow that shows this transaction is older than 90 days compared to the other shipment transactions. If there are no shipment transaction types for a lot, then I would use the receipt trans to evaluate the >90 using the  latest trans date